# How do I detect Web Debuggers on a computer, with Node JS?

Tags: javascript, http, https, interceptor

I do not want to allow Web Debuggers such as Charles Proxy, Fiddler, Wireshark, etc while using my Node JS application. I'm not fully sure what's the best way to do this. Is there a way to detect when a new program is launched in node, and then check if it's a web debugger?

I just don't want people intercepting requests sent from the node app.

I have tried getting all running processes on user's computer, and if any are a web debuggers, close my app, but this requires checking the running processes every couple seconds.

Comment: You're playing a losing game. For example, there are tools for hiding processes from process lists. Similarly, simply renaming, for example, the wireshark exe would also bypass your check. Generally, if you aren't doing the necessary verification on infrastructure you control, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no effective way for you to do this. There are more debugging tools than you could imagine to check for, and there are ways that they could be hidden beyond your ability to detect (like running them on another computer, or running your application inside a virtual machine). Besides, your application is written in an interpreted language -- any user savvy enough to use a debugging tool could just as easily open up your application and remove the code that was supposed to disable their tools.

You haven't gone into much detail about why you're trying to do this, but the fact that you're asking is a sign that your application may be structured incorrectly. If your application is communicating with a server, any access controls (e.g. on what information the client has access to, or on what operations it can perform) should be implemented on the server -- the fact that the client can "see" what is going to and from the server should not compromise the security of your system.

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible! Browser is a software, just like Charles Proxy, Fiddler, Wireshark, etc ...